# Excel VBA: Run-time error '91' on second assignment to Object variable

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am just learning Excel VBA for a school assignment. I have assigned an Object "wtCell" to be a certain cell in a certain worksheet based on some conditions.

Error: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

I am getting an error on the *second* assignment of "wtCell"

```
Sub AddWardData()

   Dim Cell As Object
   Dim Ward As Object

    Dim lngLastRow As Long ' We need to know how many rows of data are in Column J
    lngLastRow = 0
    lngLastRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' Complex formula - just ignore the details for now
    Dim w As Integer ' ward number
    w = 0
    Dim wtCell As Object

    For Each Cell In Worksheets("Data").Range("K2:K" & lngLastRow).Cells ' Iterate thru the cells collection in Row K = a copy
        w = Val(Mid(Cell.Value, 6, 2))
        If (w = 0) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = ""
            Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = ""
            Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = ""
            GoTo no_ward
        End If
        For Each Ward In Worksheets("WardData").Range("B4:B46").Cells
            If (Ward.Value = w) Then
                Cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Ward.Offset(0, 4) ' 2015 ward population
                Cell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Ward.Offset(0, 6) ' ward area
                Cell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Ward.Offset(0, 10) ' 2015 ward pop density
                GoTo ward_data_retrieved
            End If
ward_data_retrieved:
        Next
no_ward:
        If (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B5:B16").Cells, w)) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Urban"
            Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Urban"
            wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F18") ' total population for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = wtCell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = wtCell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
        ElseIf (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B21:B36").Cells, w)) Then
            Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Suburban"
            wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F39") ' total population for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = wtCell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            If (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B22:B23").Cells, w)) Then
                Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "OESA"
                wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F24") ' total population for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = wtCell.Value
                Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            ElseIf (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B28:B29").Cells, w)) Then
                Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "RRSA"
                wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F30") ' total population for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = wtCell.Value
                Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            ElseIf (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B34:B36").Cells, w)) Then
                Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "KSSA"
                wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F37") ' total population for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = wtCell.Value
                Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
                Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            End If
        ElseIf (Application.CountIf(Worksheets("WardData").Range("B41:B46").Cells, w)) Then
            wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F46") ' total population for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 8).Value = wtCell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 9).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 10).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 11).Value = wtCell.Value
            Cell.Offset(0, 12).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 2).Value ' total area for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 13).Value = wtCell.Offset(0, 6).Value ' avg density for ward type
            Cell.Offset(0, 6).Value = "Rural"
            Cell.Offset(0, 7).Value = "Rural"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

I can't figure out how to get a bold line in the code, but it is this line:

`wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F39") ' total population for ward type`

that gets highlighted by the debugger (under the first ElseIf). I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I think your issue is as highlighted in the answer below (ie you need to "Set" any object variable). Another thing to look into as a general practice is to remove the "GoTo" structure. It creates difficult to follow code and could have unintended consequences. You should be able to achieve the same result with nested if statements.

Comment: Thanks. It was pretty easy to get by without them. I was looking for a "break" implementation in VBA and GoTo was the first I found, but I wouldn't want to get in a bad habit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

`set wtCell = Worksheets("WardData").Range("F39")`

And make sure that you set all ranges to something. Not only this line.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Make sure to set `wtCell` in the other places of your code as well.